# Extend Bootstrapped module AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have a really big application and at this time I have made the general user interface but...

... the application is too big. I have a lot of controllers and directives and I don't want to load at start. Instead I make a `$http` request to a remote API who provides me the template of the `uri` to load (in a tab for example) and the name of the module to bring the template to life,  because I have a Angular wrapper which auto-loads the files with the modules for the current defining module:

```
Shx.module('mrsCatalog' ['mrsGrid', 'mrsView', 'mrsForm', 'restApi')
///...angular module code
```

it loads (those which arent loaded yet) the modules on the files `/mrs/grid/mrsGrid.js` etc.

And the problem is that I don't know how to put the code of the template cause the actual module (core) has no available the directives or controllers for making the catalog. For instance; but if I put it first and later do an `angular.bootstrap()` it results in an error because Angular attempts to load the catalog HTML code...

Comment: As of the current version of AngularJS, there is no way to load code after the application is initially bootstrapped. All code *must* be downloaded at page load.

Comment: now i think i have to manage the dom add/remove tab via jquery or vanilla after it manualy bootstrap / destory each loaded section

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can load *templates* asychronously, just not *code*. There are several AngularJS tab implementations. Check out [ui/bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/) for an example. It would be quite simple to extend it to request the content asynchronously. Or am I missing something?

Comment: yeah i know that, but that its no a problem cause what a i need its to asynchronous bootstrap unexistent modules (the application is really big and i dont want preload controllers and directives until its necessary), for that i need to make the tabs (for the global ui) not in the scope of angular cause it will attempt to compile and i have to ensure first i have loaded the module

Comment: What you are trying to do is never going to work well with AngularJS. If you skip the bootstrapping of a section of the page then you will either not have angular running there (in which case you will have a ton of nasty workarounds with $apply) or it will be a separate AngularJS app, in which case it can't share anything with  the main app or any other apps. I would suggest breaking your app into smaller pieces. But know that AngularJS apps are *significantly* smaller than apps from other frameworks and so usually not an issue. Can you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: mmm i dont think so, i believe im not explanning well my global idea, anyway tell me pleas why you think i will have a  ton of nasty workaround with $apply? i want to prevent it if is the case. thanks

Comment: haha i cant move to chat but i will work in that an promise post back an uri of the example working

Comment: We could be just talking past each other, but I meant this: angular has its own event and digest cycle that is quite independent of jQuery. So if part of the page is run by jQuery, the only way to share anything between them is with a series of callbacks that execute in an `$apply` on the angular side. But an example would be great. :-)